# CUDA C++: declare a vector with length

Tags: c++, matlab, cuda, new-operator

I recently found this won't work in my global CUDA C++ code that I plan to compile and later to be called in Matlab:

int M = 10; float V[M];
or if I were to import M value from the matlab host code.

But this works:
float V[10];

I was told there exists a function called new that I can use to avoid this problem, but I read online and am still quite confused how to use this new function, and it seems only to apply to host code, is that right? If so, it won't apply to my case then, since my host code is in matlab. Is this a way to get around this, so that I don't have to change vector lengths one by one? Thank you!

Comment: Does `M` ever need to be set at runtime (or do you know its value at compile time)?

Comment: Ideally, I want to define M in my matlab host file, so everytime I need to change M, I just have to do it in matlab, not have to recompile my cu code.

Comment: Two downvotes? I think people might be forgetting how hard it is to research something like "new" when you've just started.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about MATLAB or CUDA, but your problem is in C++. Arrays declared like that must have sizes fixed at compile-time.

#### Solution 1: Fix the size

Declare your variable M `const`. These are equivalent:

```
int const M = 10;
const int M = 10;
```

The compiler would then know that it can assume these variables will always have the same value no matter how you run the program.

#### Solution 2: C-style dynamic allocation

Dynamic allocation with `new` and `delete`. Arrays allocated on the abstract section of memory called the "free-store" (rather than on the "stack", like those arrays you have) can determine their sizes on the fly. You use it like this:

```
float * V = new V[M]; //V is a pointer to some freestore memory
//You use it and pass it like you would a normal array:
V[2] = 5.5;
int x = some_func(V);

//But after you're done, you should manually free the memory
delete [] V; //don't forget the [], since you used [] in the allocation
```

I don't recommend this, because of the possiblity of forgetting to delete the memory.

#### Solution 3: Automatic memory management with C++'s `vector`

In C++, the work of memory management can be hidden behind structures called classes.

```
#include<vector>
using std::vector;

vector<float> V(M); //V is a vector of floats, with initial size M
//You use it like a normal array
V[2] = 5.5;
//But to pass it as an array, you need to pass a pointer to the first element
int x = some_func(&V[0]); //read as &(V[0]): pass in the address of V[0]
```

#### Solution 3b: CUDA-compatible vector

> Thrust is a C++ template library for CUDA based on the Standard Template Library (STL). Thrust allows you to implement high performance parallel applications with minimal programming effort through a high-level interface that is fully interoperable with CUDA C.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/#vectors

#### Conclusion

If you're using fixed sizes, I recommend solution 1. If you're using sizes determined during runtime, I recommend vector.

(By the way, when you pass an ordinary array to a function, you are actually passing a pointer to the first element, NOT the array. The name of the array is automatically converted to a pointer type.)

Comment: Technically, C uses malloc/free instead of new/delete, which don't do the same thing. I know, I know.

Comment: Or you can use a pre-processor statement like `#define M 10` to make sure it is _really_ constant. For a static array, this is arguably the right way to go.

Comment: Thank you! I had solution 1 before, but that did not work, but will try the other two solutions.

Comment: Worth pointing out that Solution 3 isn't applicable to this case. CUDA has no C++ standard library container support in GPU code.

Comment: @chappjc What would be the problem with just declaring a const global variable?
@talonmies I don't understand. If CUDA wants an array pointer, `&V[0]` would give it an array pointer. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Alright, apparently there's a CUDA-compatible vector in something called Thrust.

Comment: @leewangzhong: Nothing wrong with it. I just think it is cleaner to have magic numbers as defines in some header rather than a global const.

Comment: I tried the above new operator in method 2, but it generates error message not applicable to global code but host code. Since I am writing this in a global code to be called by matlab host code, is there any other way besides the above three to solve this problem? Thanks!